# Why does the '+' operator behave the way it does for Matlab strings?

Tags: string, matlab, operator-overloading

In Matlab, the following statement gives a numeric output . .

```
>> 'abc' + 'def'

ans =

   197   199   201
```

In C++, the output of the following

```
std::string("abc") + std::string("def")
```

...would give the arguably more useful...

```
abcdef
```

A little more exploration gives..

```
>> a = 'abc'

a =

abc

>> whos
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  a         1x3                 6  char
```

This suggests that my variable `a` is a `char` type. However, we know that this is not equivalent to a C type char, as it is an object that knows its size dimensions etc.

Therefore, my questions are: 
What use would this numeric output be?

...leading to

Why would they design it to behave like that?

Comment: "Because it is how the language [and API] was defined." That's really all there is to it. The use of `+` for string-concat is not universally accepted as correct. It is even considered a "small design flaw" in Scala (which borrowed it from Java), for instance.

Comment: I would argue that the rampant operator "redefinition" in C++ is actually harmful - you need to read the docs just to figure out what the simplest of operators does.  Matlab lets you do it as well, to some extent - but people just don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because a string in Matlab is literally just an array of `char` type, so it's equivalent to:

```
[97 98 99] + [100 101 102]
```

It is not set in stone that `+` means "concatenate".  If you want string concatenation in Matlab, you can always do:

```
['abc' 'def']
```

Comment: So I should think of it a raw chars in a container?

Comment: @learnvst: If you like.  But it is literally just a row vector of integers (`char`s).

Comment: The function `horzcat` (horizontal concatenate) does the same as ['abc' def'], as another example